# React-native back button going to first page

Tags: react-native

I have a link from "Test" page to "TestDetails" page. but When i click this.props.navigation.goBack(null) on "TestDetails" page , it takes me to the first page which is "Home" instead of "Test". Here's my index.js. I really dont know how arrived at this though. Pls what am I doing wrong

```
const HomeScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,

    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({

    })
  }
});
const LoginScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Login,

     navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({

    })
  }
});

const SignupScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Signup: {
    screen: Signup,

    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({

    })
  }
});

const TestsScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Tests: {
    screen: Tests,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: '400',
        color: '#333',
        fontFamily: 'Nunito-Regular',
        fontSize: 18
      },
      headerStyle: {
        elevation: 0, //remove shadow on Android
        shadowOpacity: 0, //remove shadow on iOS
        fontWeight: 400,
      },
      title: "Consumer tests",
      headerLeft:(<Icon.Button name="menu" size={35} 
backgroundColor="transparent" color="#2a486c" onPress={() => 
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())}>

              </Icon.Button>      
      ),
    })
  }
});

const TestDetailsScreen = createStackNavigator({
  TestDetails: {
    screen: TestDetails,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({

    })
  }
});

const SettingsScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Settings: {
    screen: Settings,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      title: "Settings",
      headerLeft:(<Icon.Button name="arrow-back" backgroundColor="transparent" color="black" onPress={() => navigation.dismiss()}>
                  <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}></Text>
              </Icon.Button>      
      ),
    })     
  },
});


const drawernav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,  
  },
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,  
  },
  SignUp: {
    screen: SignupScreen,  
  },
  Tests: {
    screen: TestsScreen,  
  },
  TestDetails: {
    screen: TestDetailsScreen,  
  },
  Settings: {
    screen: SettingsScreen,  
  },
},{
    contentComponent: SideMenu,
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => createAppContainer(drawernav));
```

Pls what am I doing wrong

Comment: Can u tell me , How you navigate from one screen to another?

Answer (score 0):

```
const LoginScreen = createStackNavigator({

    Home: {

        screen: Login,

        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({

        })
    }
})
```

why Home: here?

could you add info from console or you are not receiving error or warnings?
Remember always refer official guides https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation

Comment: Cos that's the home page. It's the page I want to display when the app is launched

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed the `react-native-navigation` definition, like below code snippet.
`goBack()` and `goBack(null)` same that the same!

back to your question:
like @Michael post, you'd better check your navigation stack fist

```
  export interface NavigationScreenProp<S, P = NavigationParams> {
    state: S;
    dispatch: NavigationDispatch;
    goBack: (routeKey?: string | null) => boolean;
    dismiss: () => boolean;

    navigate(options: {
      routeName:
        | string
        | {
            routeName: string;
            params?: NavigationParams;
            action?: NavigationNavigateAction;
            key?: string;
          };
      params?: NavigationParams;
      action?: NavigationAction;
      key?: string;
    }): boolean;
```